# For Loop for Openpyxl Chart Position

Tags: python, excel, charts, openpyxl

I am trying to make a for loop to iterate through a list of chart names and positions to make it easier to add charts to excel using openpyxl. Here is what I have tried so far.

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.chart import BarChart, Reference, Series

def trysomething():

    letterlist=['B', 'J', 'R', 'Z']
    numlist=[22, 38, 54, 70]
    position=[]
    for k in letterlist:
        for l in numlist:
            pos = k+str(l)
            position.append(pos)

    chartlist=['chart']
    chartnum=[]
    for j in range(1,6):
        chartnum.append(j)

    cha=[]
    for h in chartlist:
        for s in chartnum:
            ch=h+str(s)
            cha.append(ch)

    wb = Workbook()
    ws = wb.active
    for i in range(10):
        ws.append([i])

    values1 = Reference(ws, min_col=1, min_row=1, max_col=1, max_row=10)
    chart1 = BarChart()
    chart1.add_data(values1)

    values2 = Reference(ws, min_col=1, min_row=1, max_col=1, max_row=10)
    chart2 = BarChart()
    chart2.add_data(values2)

    values3 = Reference(ws, min_col=1, min_row=1, max_col=1, max_row=10)
    chart3 = BarChart()
    chart3.add_data(values3)

    values4 = Reference(ws, min_col=1, min_row=1, max_col=1, max_row=10)
    chart4 = BarChart()
    chart4.add_data(values4)

    values5 = Reference(ws, min_col=1, min_row=1, max_col=1, max_row=10)
    chart5 = BarChart()
    chart5.add_data(values5)

    for a, b in zip(iter(cha), iter(position)):
         print(a,b)
         ws.add_chart(str(a), str(b))

     wb.save("SampleChart.xlsx")

trysomething()
```

When I print(a,b) it outputs the correct chart with the correct chart position, however, I does not work for adding the chart.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Do you have any idea why:
for i in range(1, 4)
ws2_obj.add_chart(c1, ws2_obj.cell(row=1, column=i*int(step)))

is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Workbook().active.add_chart()` takes a [Chart](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/2.3.3/charts/introduction.html) object and a `string` cell position. When printing the values (chart, chart position) you should expect to see an instance of [Chart](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/2.3.3/charts/introduction.html) `<class 'openpyxl.chart.bar_chart.BarChart'>` and a `'string'`, but instead you see `a` and `b` are both `<str>` (string) objects, so your code is passing two `string` objects to the `.add_chart()`, no `Chart`.

You'll want to do something like create a `chart_list` and iterate over it:

```
charts_list = [chart1, chart2, chart3, chart4, chart5]

for a, b in zip(iter(charts_list), iter(position)):
     # print(type(a))  # <class 'openpyxl.chart.bar_chart.BarChart'>
     # print(type(b))  # <type 'str'>
     ws.add_chart(a, b)
```

Viewing the created Excel file should resemble something like the following with 5 charts.

Hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: And what does it happen when you do not know how many graphs there are.. maybe there will be 100 graphs...  is there any  way to rewrite this repetition: values1 = Reference(ws, min_col=1, min_row=1, max_col=1, max_row=10)
    chart1 = BarChart()
    chart1.add_data(values1)

    values2 = Reference(ws, min_col=1, min_row=1, max_col=1, max_row=10)
    chart2 = BarChart()
    chart2.add_data(values2)

    values3 = Reference(ws, min_col=1, min_row=1, max_col=1, max_row=10)
    chart3 = BarChart()
    chart3.add_data(values3)